# django model choice field does not render as radio button

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I am trying to display a radio group as opposed to the default drop down.  My form looks like this:

```
class ConditionForm(forms.ModelForm):

    state = forms.ChoiceField(choices=STATE_TYPES, widget=forms.RadioSelect())

    class Meta:
        model = Customer
        fields = ('state',)
```

I also tried this:
class ConditionForm(forms.ModelForm):

```
    class Meta:
        model = Customer
        fields = ('state',)
        widgets = {
        'state': forms.RadioSelect(),
    }
```

My model looks like this:

```
STATE_TYPES = (
    (0, 'Type 2'),
    (1, 'Type 1'),
)
class Customer(models.Model):
    state = models.IntegerField(choices=STATE_TYPES, default=0, null=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)
```

my template looks like:

```
{{ form.state }}
```

This outputs a single dropdown as opposed to 4 radio buttons.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I think there was a problem in my css and using django widget tweaks.  I removed adding css from django widget tweaks and added it to the form and it worked.

Like this:

```
state = forms.ChoiceField(choices=STATE_TYPES, widget=forms.RadioSelect(attrs={'class':'radio_1', 'name': 'name2'}))
```

Answer (score 0):

You're supposed to just output the field, not iterate through its attributes. Just:

```
{{ form.state }}
```

Comment: I need to apply css to each radio button is why i itereated.  Even when I do {{ form.state }} a dropdown shows and not a radio group.  Do you know why this might be happening?